# Blender Composting Material into SceneKit

Tags: ios, blender, scenekit

I created a 3D object in blender that has a material to it that I created in blender's compositing pane. I exported my object as a dae and loaded into the scene but it doesn't have the clearish watery material that I get when I do "Render" in blender, it just has the viewport color, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Using the "compositing pane" means you made a node based material, possibly a cycles material, node based materials are rather specific to blender and don't export to game engines very well.

Set the render engine to Blender Render and then setup your material without nodes.

If you google [blender material export scenekit](https://www.google.com/#q=blender+material+export+scenekit) you should find some more tips.